# Check if a value exists in an JavaScript object as you type in TextBox using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have textbox in which user can enter any value. As user is entering this value, on every key-up, I need to check if that value already exists in $scope.arrayObject. I can do this by adding key-kp event to the textbox and then do the required stuff.

Is it possible to utilize AngularJs data binding feature here and without manually adding key-down or key-up event we achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, bind your input element with a scope variable of the controller.

```
<input ng-model="modalVariable">
<label ng-show="duplicateValue"> Entered Value Already Exists </label>
```

Adding up to the answer, once you're done with the data binding, add a watch to the modal variable inside your controller :

```
    $scope.$watch('modalVariable', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if ($scope.yourArray.indexOf(modalVariable) !== -1) {
        $scope.duplicateValue = true;
      } else {
        $scope.duplicateValue = false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This makes sense. Is it possible to add a label below the textbox and show it only when there is a duplicate entry in the $scope.array ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter.

```
<input ng-model="name">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="aname in arrayObject | name">{{aname}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am not sure either:)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. As a text box, you need only to add a input with the ng-model attribute, such as:

```
<input ng-model="insert variable name here">
```

And then, use the AngularJS databinding inside the HTML for that ng-model value, such as:

```
{{ insert variable name here }}
```

For a Hello World example, it would be similar to...

```
<input ng-model="name" type="text">
Hello {{ name }}
```

And do remember to add a "ng-app" before the element so it actually works. If you make a module with a name, use ng-app="module name" in the html or the body tag, as the tag with ng-app needs to have the input inside it for the binding to work.

In the Hello World case, the "Hello" would be a fixed string, but the "name" would change in real-time with the value of the input field.

For a full HTML example...

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    Hello {{ name }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, if you wish to check if a entry in the field is valid, you can use the ng-class directive, similar to...

```
<input ng-class="{invalid: name !== arrayObject} {valid: name === arrayObject}" ng-model="name">
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am aware of data binding expression `{{}}` but this alone will not help me. I also need to check if the value entered in the textbox already exists as user is typing

Comment: You haven't answered the main question, how to monitor the value of the text box to check for values inside the array ??